# Drop Non-equivalent Multiindex Rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

**Goal**

If sub-column `min` equals to sub-column `max` and if `min` and `max` sub-column do not equal to each other in **any** of the column (ao, his, cyp1a2s, cyp3a4s in this case), drop the row.

**Example**

```py
arrays = [np.array(['ao', 'ao', 'hia', 'hia', 'cyp1a2s', 'cyp1a2s', 'cyp3a4s', 'cyp3a4s']),
          np.array(['min', 'max', 'min', 'max', 'min', 'max', 'min', 'max'])]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['',''])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, float('nan'), float('nan'), 0, 0], 
                            [1, 1, 0, 0, float('nan'), 1, 0, 0],
                            [0, 2, 0, 0, float('nan'), float('nan'), 1, 1],]), index=['1', '2', '3'], columns=index)
df

    ao      hia     cyp1a2s cyp3a4s
    min max min max min max min max
1   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 NaN NaN 0.0 0.0
2   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 NaN 1.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0
```

**Want**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, float('nan'), float('nan'), 0, 0]]), index=['1'], columns=index)
df

    ao      hia     cyp1a2s cyp3a4s
    min max min max min max min max
1   1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 NaN NaN 0.0 0.0
```

**Attempt**

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['min'].map(str) == x['max'].map(str), axis=1)

KeyError: ('min', 'occurred at index 1')
```

**Note**

The actual dataframe has 50+ columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for `DataFrame` by second levels of `MultiIndex`, replace `NaN`s:

```
df1 = df.xs('min', axis=1, level=1).fillna('nan')
df2 = df.xs('max', axis=1, level=1).fillna('nan')
```

Or convert data to strings:

```
df1 = df.xs('min', axis=1, level=1).astype('str')
df2 = df.xs('max', axis=1, level=1).astype('str')
```

Compare Dataframes by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if all `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df1.eq(df2).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
    ao       hia      cyp1a2s     cyp3a4s     
   min  max  min  max     min max     min  max
1  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0     NaN NaN     0.0  0.0
```

Comment: It is very kind to explain the code (and with helpful links)! I wonder why `df.apply` will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason df.apply() didn't work is you needed to reference 2 levels of columns.

Also .map(str) was invalid for mapping from float64... used .astype(str)

The following work for >1 columns:

```
eqCols = ['cyp1a2s','hia']
neqCols = list(set(df.xs('min', level=1, axis=1).columns) - set(eqCols))
EQ = lambda r,c : r[c]['min'].astype(str) == r[c]['max'].astype(str)
df[df.apply(lambda r: ([EQ(r,c) for c in eqCols][0]) & ([(not EQ(r,c)) for c in neqCols][0]), axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hi, I have 50+ columns. Repeating for each column would be time-consuming.

Comment: See latest changes... divided into Equality columns and NotEqual columns; ultimately doing the same # of comparisons.. not sure which is faster df.apply() or df.eq()?